# How to append unit of measure to insert input?

Tags: angular

In my angular app i have an API which return unit of measure of each product, then when changing it's quantity i would set it inside the input of quantity without changing it's value something like this:

[image]

Here is how my input looks like:

```
  <div class="input-group group-qta ml-md-auto">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-dark"
        (click)="minus(plu, plu.um != 'PZ' ? 50 : 1)"
        [disabled]="plu.qta <= 1"
      >
        -
      </button>
    </div>
    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control qta"
      disabled
      [value]="plu.qta"
    />
    <span>{{ plu.um }}</span> // span with UM but look's ugly
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-dark"
        (click)="plus(plu, plu.um != 'PZ' ? 50 : 1)"
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How could i reach it by adding it inside the input but still by getting it's value as 100 without gr or other um?

Comment: You want to retrieve the input value given by the user in the component without the unit?

Comment: @NicholasK yes and add it to the layout as in the screen

Comment: Do you mind creating a stackblitz for the problem? There is some code missing in the question.